# Reconstruct a pentagon from the midpoints P, Q, R, S, T of its sides

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, plane-geometry

This is a problem that comes with an answer, but I can't understand it. My book says:

"We denote $H_A$ simply by $A$. Then $P{\circ}Q{\circ}R=X$, where $X$ is the fourth vertex of the parallelogram  $(P,Q,R)$. Furthermore, $X{\circ}S{\circ}T=A$. Thus we have constructed A".

And the rest is obviously simple as we can reflect our result to find the other points. But I don't understand why $(X,S,T,A)$ forms a parallelogram. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: In a triangle $ABC$ consider the three midpoints of the sides, $M_1$ the midpoint of $AB$, $M_2$ the midpoint of $BC$ and $M_3$ the midpoint of $CA$, then $A M_1 M_2 M_3 $ and $B M_2 M_3 M_1 $ and $C  M_3 M_1 M_2 $ are all parallelograms.

Comment: You should say that your pentagon is planar and not 3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

We have [Varignon's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem), which says that if we take any quadrilateral and connect its midpoints, the resulting shape is a parallelogram.  So taking $P$, $Q$, and $R$, we find $X$, the midpoint of $AD$, the fourth side of the quadrilateral $ABCD$.

But $X$ is on a diagonal of the pentagon, and as such it divides it into a quadrilateral *and a triangle*.  And if we take the midpoints of a triangle, we have the [medial triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_triangle), which we can spin across its sides (forming more parallelograms) to get the actual corners of the triangle.  This particular formulation has found the one between $X$ and $T$, which is also the corner of the pentagon between $P$ and $T$, which we'll call $A$.

Once we have one of the corners (and know which pair of midpoints it's between), we can finish the job by simply reflecting each successive corner across another midpoint.

Comment: How do you know $X$ is in the diagonal of the pentagon? This assumes the diagonals of a pentagon are parallel to a side of the pentagon itself, which although obviously true for a regular pentagon, I have failed to find a proof for every pentagon.

Comment: How do you get that assumption?  All we can say about X is that it must be (as it completes the parallelogram) the midpoint of AD, so it's on the diagonal.  Hang on, drawing.